# why we access like that getActivity().findViewById()

Tags: android

When a layout , which is defined for a `Fragment` and used inside `setContentView()` method and it has no relation with `Activity` .
then why we need `Activity` Reference to access it .

so I want to create a `ListView` , inside a `Fragment` . than i have to create it inside `Activity` layout or inside `Fragment` layout .

Hey Neil , i have a question because every time I have made a mistake because , i am performing this

```
TextView txt = ( TextView ) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt);
txt.setText("nayak nahi , khalnayak hun mein");
```

inside `oncreateView()` so it is creating problem but when ever i am implementing this inside 
`onActivityCreated()` , it is working , so can you please tell me Why this is happening .

Comment: Because that's where the `findViewById()` method is defined?

Comment: have you looked into ListFragment?

Comment: txt.setText() is awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** define a `ListView` in a layout for your `Fragment`. Try something like this in your fragment to define a alternative layout

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    _baseView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null); //where base view is your upper most parent in your layout
    return _baseView;
}
```

Then in your `onActivityCreated` you can use `_baseView.findViewById('yourListView')` to set your `ListView`. I don't know if this is best practice but it works perfectly for me.

Comment: See the life cycle of a fragment here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle the onActivityCreated is called after onCreateView

Comment: what is the question? Does a error occur or don't you know how to get that textview?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to find the view by getActivity(), you should do that after onCreateView is called, because till onCreateView is called the view of fragment is null. So you can do:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    TextView txt = ( TextView ) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txt.setText("nayak nahi , khalnayak hun mein");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment you should use its View but getActivity:

```
public View onCreateView(…){
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_xml_file, container, false);
ListView ListNewsBelarus = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewId);
return rootView;
}
```